# Html new lines in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in mvc with column property **.Encoded(false)**
In the controller I replaced **Environment.NewLine** with

```
 <br>
```

But in the view there is a text instead of real new line. I tried both:

```
 <br> or <br/>
```

It is not working either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved it myself.
in the Grid:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Address).Width(150).Encoded(false).ClientTemplate("#= getHtmlNewLinesString(Address) #");
```

and in the js:

```
 function getHtmlNewLinesString(text) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\n', 'g');
        return text.replace(regexp, '<br>');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `css` to solve this.

in `html` file:

```
col.Bound(c => c.Text)
              //.Encoded(false)
                .Title("text")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { Class = "keepLineBreak" });
```

in `css` file:

```
.keepLineBreak {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

The filter is not working in this case because the cell includes `<br>`.