# Newline operator doesn't work inside class property getter

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app I have a column in one of my views which I'm populating from a string property which concatenates two of my other properties from said class. In my getter for my combined string, I've tried a few ways to add a new line so that the data will be stacked (since it's inside a grid), such as passing \n inside of the concatenated string. I've also tried using string builder to Append the strings individually and pass in an AppendLine() call between the Append(string1) and Append(string2) method calls. Neither approach is working, but works fine with the DateTime's which are converted to strings (as is the integer values that aren't working).

I tested this with another property that consisted of DateTimes and had no issues once I converted them to strings:

```
public string CombinedStrings
        {
            get
            {
                string efDate = EffectiveDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                string exDate = ExpirationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                return string.Format("{0} \n{1}", efDate, exDate);
            }
        }
```

Here are the two columns in my grid side-by-side. As I indicated, the code above works fine with my DateTime, but applying the same code to the other property which my grid item is bound to, does not force a new line.

[image]

Note: The 100 and 1 values should be on separate lines like the DateTimes beside it.

Here's an example of the code I've tried so far with no luck:

```
        public string CombinedIntegerProperties
        {
            get
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(CommittedVolume);
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.Append(TotalVolume);
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and

```
        public string CombinedIntegerProperties
        {
            get
            {
                string cmtVol = CommittedVolume.ToString("G");
                string totVol = TotalVolume.ToString();
                return $"{cmtVol} \n{totVol}";
                
            }
        }
```

and

```
        public string CombinedIntegerProperties
        {
            get
            {
                string cmtVol = CommittedVolume.ToString();
                string totVol = TotalVolume.ToString();
                return string.Format("{0}\n{1}", cmtVol, totVol);                
            }
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could it be grid settings? Does the grid column with the problem accept newlines/multi-line text?

Comment: Hey @haldo, I assume so because my DateTime's are converted to Strings and as you see in my screenshot, they are stacked vertically.

Comment: My guess is the DateTime column wraps because the column width is too narrow and this causes the DateTimes to wrap. The Numbers in the first column are not as long as the dates so they fit without wrapping. You can easily test this by using numbers in the first column that are as long as your dates to see if they do in fact wrap. That said, in a web page you want `<br />` and not `\n` to make a new line in HTML. Though I don't know how to use the Kendo-grid, so I may be off point here.

Comment: @quaabaam you're absolutely right. This is what is happening. However, when I tried to bind the two properties into a single column in Kendo, I ran into several errors trying to pass in the second property. The Kendo grid seems well documented, but I can't seem to find anyone else attempting to achieve this with any similar code. I assume maybe I could chain an HtmlAttributes() method call and pass in a break that way?

Comment: This post may help... [html-new-lines-in-kendo-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910339/html-new-lines-in-kendo-grid)

Comment: Exactly the solution I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html new lines in kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910339/html-new-lines-in-kendo-grid)